# Converting txt file to csv in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a tab separated text file after executing some command in powershell i want to convert this tab separated file into csv now how can i do so?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you end up with a tab-delimited file? It is likely you are making things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Sorry for not telling detail. Actualy I am executing get-process command in a loop to get the detail about a process in a text file and updating it in some interval.Now when process stops my scripts also stops.
Here I want that before stoping the script the text file should be read and the data should be shown in a csv file along with its headers..Becoz opening it in MSExcel wud give gud looking results..

Comment: In your scenario it would be better to export your data directly to csv. Something like this: `while ($true) {sleep 5; ps iexplore | select Handles, NPM, PM, WS, VM, CPU, Id, Name, @{N="SampleDateTime";E={(get-date)}} | export-csv -Append -NoTypeInformation process.csv}`

Comment: IN this case i have a prob with appending data..dats y i dint tried dat..-Append will not work..

Comment: It works on my machine. Please consider posting the sample code where append is not working as expected (as a separate question).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A tab separated text file could be treated as a CSV file with a tab instead of comma as its delimiter.
To convert:

```
import-csv tabdelimitedfile.txt -delimiter "`t" | export-csv csvfile.csv
```

Comment: Adding -NoType to the end of that line will get rid of the "#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" line at the top of the output file.

Comment: This seems to add double quotes, is there a way to omit double quotes?