# PowerShell - How to export MSSQL Report into CSV file

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell can I export/convert MSSQL Report into CSV file?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried to do so far?

Comment: Thanks Unome for responding. I haven't tried one yet, is it possible to convert .rdl file into CSV using PowerShell commands? If concretely knows that it's possible then I can spent some time for that.

Comment: I posted my best attempt at an answer, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if its possible to convert .rdl to CSV, but there is already a post about converting .txt to .csv [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970312/converting-txt-file-to-csv-in-powershell)

They were able to do that conversion using this

```
import-csv tabdelimitedfile.txt -delimiter "`t" | export-csv csvfile.csv
```

I looked up the [documentation](http://ss64.com/ps/export-csv.html) for export-csv and found

> **Export-Csv**
>
> Export a PowerShell object to a comma-separated values (CSV) file.
>
> Syntax
>
> Export-CSV [[-Delimiter] char] [-Path] string -InputObject psobject
>          [-Encoding string] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-NoTypeInformation]
>             [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [CommonParameters]
>
> Export-CSV [-UseCulture] [-Path] string -InputObject psobject 
>           [-Encoding string] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-NoTypeInformation]
>             [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [CommonParameters]

I'd say your best bet would be to be to use that as a base to start off and follow the documentation. I didn't see anything in the docs specifying what types the import object has to be, but I didn't see any examples either that did not use `.txt` More documentation for the import-csv can be found [here](http://ss64.com/ps/import-csv.html).

A worst case scenario workaround would be to convert your .rdl file into a .txt file and then use this method, you should be able to export databases into .txt files.

Good luck!

Comment: Unome - Thanks for the research, this giving some starting point.

Comment: No problem, good luck, and if you find the exact answer, pls post here.