# converting text file to CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, export-to-csv

i have written some powershell code to read a very large .txt file, select certain lines and put them into a CSV. the problem is that the file is formatted like this:

```
header1: Data1 
header2: Data1 
header3: Data1 
header4: Data1 
header1: Data2 
header2: Data2 
header3: Data2
header4: Data2
```

and i need to convert it to this:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
data1,data1,data1,data1
data2,data2,data2,data2
```

the code is this:

```
   $path = get-location
    $textfile = Get-FileName $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\


    $writefile = "$path\data2.csv"
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($textfile)
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $writefile
    $writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', "Policy","Schedule Type","Retention Level","Host")

        for(;;) {

                $line = $reader.ReadLine() #
                if ($null -eq $line) {
                break
                }

                $data = $line.Split(":")

                if ($null -ne $data[0]) {
                $newdata0 = $data[0].trimstart(" ")
                }
                if ($null -ne $data[1]) {
                $newdata1 = $data[1].trimstart(" ")
                }

                if ($newdata0 -eq "Policy")  {$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', $newdata1,$null,$null,$null)}

                if ($newdata0 -eq "Schedule Type") {$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', $null,$newdata1,$null,$null)}

                if ($newdata0 -eq "Retention Level") {$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', $null,$null,$newdata1,$null)}

                if ($newdata0 -eq "Host") {$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', $null,$null,$null,$newdata1)}    

            }



    $reader.Close()
    $writer.Close()
```

but i end up with this (actual data):

```
Policy,Schedule Type,Retention Level,Host
FS-Win-Servers-Tokyo-DACS_ONLY,,,
,FULL (0),,
,,infinity (9),
,,,opback03e.options-it.com
DB-Win-Exch2013-ADB11,,,
,INCR (1),,
,,6 months (6),
,,,opback03e.options-it.com
DB-Win-Exch2013-MDB11,,,
,INCR (1),,
,,6 months (6),
,,,opback03e.options-it.com
DB-Win-Exch2013-MDB10,,,
,INCR (1),,
,,6 months (6),
,,,opback03e.options-it.com
```

i think i am going about this code wrong or maybe just need to find a way to reformat the csv?

Comment: I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8970351/5341953

Comment: thanks but i have the CSV file. the problem is in my code, i cannot get the data to write on one line of the CSV. it writes to the correct column  but i done know how to get the data on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is each call to $writer.WriteLine is advancing the line in the destination file that you're writing to. You need to collect the information on each loop but only write once every 4th loop, this might work:

```
  $loopCounter = 0

  for(;;) {

            $line = $reader.ReadLine() #
            if ($null -eq $line) {
            break
            }

            $data = $line.Split(":")

            if ($null -ne $data[0]) {
            $newdata0 = $data[0].trimstart(" ")
            }
            if ($null -ne $data[1]) {
            $newdata1 = $data[1].trimstart(" ")
            }

            if ($newdata0 -eq "Policy")  {$data1=$newdata}

            if ($newdata0 -eq "Schedule Type") {$data2=$newdata}

            if ($newdata0 -eq "Retention Level") {$data3=$newdata}

            if ($newdata0 -eq "Host") {$data4=$newdata}    


            if (($loopCounter % 4) -eq 3) {$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', $data1, $data2, $data3, $data4)}        

            $loopCounter++

        }
```

Comment: ive done some more editing but this is the concept i needed! thanks very much! very apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to make something look for repetition to act as a record delimiter (replacing end of line).

```
$header = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
Get-Content test.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '(?<Header>[^:]+): *(?<Value>.+)$' } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($header.Contains($matches.Header)) {
        # End of record start again.
        $header.Clear()
        # Output
        $psObject
    }
    if ($header.Count -eq 0) {
        # Start of the record. Create an object to hold it.
        $psObject = New-Object PSObject
    }

    # Add the current header and value to the object.
    $psObject | Add-Member $matches.Header $matches.Value
    # Add the header name to the record controller
    $header.Add($matches.Header)    
}
# Output the last entry from the file (no end detection)
$psObject
```

Comment: hi yes i was doing that with  $data = $line.Split(":") when i ran your code it still formats the data across rows like header : data but i need it to match each header (which repeat over and over down the list) and spread the data across rows instead of lines.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. This turns your vertically arranged data set into a set of PSObjects which have properties based on each of the header values. Since it's an array of PSObject you can output it however you see fit (if the parser worked). All you need to do is apply a format, or export it. e.g. `Export-Csv` or `Format-Table` or `ConvertTo-Csv`.

Comment: sorry my fault, misunderstood. i have rerun the code and exported to CSV. which does send it horizontally, however the headers are not matched so it just repeats horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: Can you improve the data sample in your original post? That's the basis for the parser and it works well for that. However, if the real data significantly differs the record loop detection process may be flawed.

Comment: This worked great for me @ChrisDent! 
I'm curious as to how the Regex (is it?) in the Where-Object invocation works, especially for the Header. I know it's been ages you gave this answer, but could you please explain that a little?